# How to use same Topology Manager DB from 2 CME?

Tags: web8, topology-manager

I installed 2 "SDL Web 8" in 2 servers("ServerA" and "ServerB").

And those 2 "SDL Web 8" are using same "Tridion CM" DB and "Topology Manager DB",
because one of them is used only for publishing to improve publish performance.

When installing Web 8, I specified "Content Manager environment ID" as following.

- ServerA:"ServerAEnvironmentId"
- ServerB:"ServerBEnvironmentId"

And I modified "TtmCmEnvironment" by Topology Manager, and now "Get-TtmCmEnvironment" command returns following results.

```
CoreServiceRootUrl     : net.tcp://ServerA:2660
WebsiteRootUrl         : http://ServerA:80
CoreServiceCredentials : "AuthenticationType":"Windows", "UserName":"MTSUser", "Password":"********"
Id                     : ServerAEnvironmentId
ExtensionProperties    : {}

CoreServiceRootUrl     : net.tcp://ServerB:2660
WebsiteRootUrl         : http://ServerB:80
CoreServiceCredentials : "AuthenticationType":"Windows", "UserName":"MTSUser", "Password":"********"
Id                     : ServerBEnvironmentId
ExtensionProperties    : {}
```

When I try to remove Topology Type by "Remove-TtmCdTopologyType" command in ServerA, following error occurs.(This message is not exactly same because I translated it from Japanese.)

```
Failed to remove "CdTopologyTypeData". Could not connect to 'net.tcp://ServerB:2660' by 'Windows' authentication.
```

Why ServerA tries to connect to ServerB even though "ServerAEnvironmentId" is specified during installing?

How is it possible to use same Topology Manager DB from 2 SDL Web 8?

Regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have multiple CM Servers in a (logical) CM Environment, you should have only one `CmEnvironment` entity in Topology Manager, not multiple.

In such a scaled out Environment, it is **essential** that all CM Servers use the same CM Environment ID. That is why you can specify a CM Environment ID in the installer and why the default value is derived from the CM DB info: this yields a CM Environment ID which is common for all CM Servers in a single CM Environment by default.

You should leave the `CoreServiceRootUrl` as `net.tcp://localhost:2660`, so that each Topology Manager node (note that you will automatically scale out Topology Manager too) will use the CM node on the same server.

You should ensure that the `WebsiteRootUrl` uses the domain name of the load balancer, rather than of an individual back-end node. Again, this is the reason why you can specify the CM Website Root URL in the installer.

Comment: When installing SDL Web8 into ServerB with same CM Environment ID as ServerA, an error occured while installing, the error indicates "CM Environment ID" have to be unique.So I created new DB and installed into ServerB by using it with same CM Environment ID as ServerA. After that I modified Topology Manager's configuration file to use same DB as ServerA. So far it's working fine.

Comment: The would be a defect in the installer. Please report that with SDL Support.

Comment: I contacted to SDL Support about this issue. The problem of installer is revised on SDL Web 8.5. On SDL Web 8.1 above workaround is no problem.